# Navigate frame on other page

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation

How can I navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 when a button placed on Page 1 is clicked?

Is it possible to use `Mainframe.Navigate(typeof(page 2));`?

I don't know how to get access to parent frame located on other page. Here is my page scheme:

[image: Page scheme]

Comment: have you tried `Frame.Navigate(typeOf(page2));` on click of a button on Page1?

Comment: Do you have multiple `Frame`s ? It is not very clear from your description. Could you post some code so that we can clearly see what is going on and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @StefanW. Unfortunately none of those suggestions are relevant, as the question is regarding UWP and the linked documentation is for Windows Phone 8 and earlier and for WPF

Comment: I don't have access to MainFrame from Page 1

Comment: my bad, didnt notice it's uwp sorry.

Comment: I've tried to use grid.Parent as SubFramePage; but it takes frame of whole app, not that one I wish to

Comment: as i understand, are you want to access page2 in frame of page1 it is very easy create a frame element in page 1 and give it a name then navigate     YourFrameName.Navigate(typeof(Page2)); on button click and you should handle page2 click events from page 2 code behind